# Achieve Global Scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, scope

I have some sort of Scope issue that I cannot solve.  The picture is worth a thousand words. When the OK or REJ buttons call the reject() function passing the user_id as id as a parameter to the reject function.

I get a JS console error in Firefox: "ReferenceError: BUUS123US163 is not defined".

Which is odd that even the error is defined, that is, it does list the unique id that is desired.  I did try shallow and deep copies of data into a Global array called theUsers which did not work yet. What am I missing about what I think is a Scope issue?

Update:
 JSON.parse error
At the .catch clause of reject() function

```
// function getting: JSON.parse error

    function reject(id) {

      console.log("hey: reject ran... ");
      // User Data
      const data2 = {
        user_id: '',
        utility: 'delete'
      }

      data2.user_id = id;

      // // POST  :  pass user
      http.post('http://localhost:9999/Password/empapproval', data2)
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    }

// http.post calls the following:

    post(url, data) {

        console.log("easyHttp is running ...");


        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            console.log("easyHttp Promise is running ...");

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => resolve(data))
                .catch(err => reject(err));
        });

    }
```

[image: picture of html, code, and console]

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: What is `this.id` supposed to be? `reject()` isn't a method, it doesn't have a `this` context.

Comment: I think you need quotes around `'${}'` so it does not treat your data as a variable name.

Comment: Maybe `this.id` is just supposed to be `id`?

Comment: @DaveAnkin Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that if you are passing the id as a simple argument to the reject and ok functions, it would need to be quoted to be evaluated that way, resulting in `reject ("some-id")` vs `reject(some-id)`, in order for that to work the code on line 224 should be

```js
`<td><button onclick="reject('${d.user_id}')" class="" ...`
```

vs

```js
`<td><button onclick="reject(${d.user_id})" class="" ...`
```

Also, `this.id` doesn't make a lot of sense, because the `this` context only provides you a reference to your element when you use jquery event listeners, not html "onclick" attribute listeners. It appears it should be just `id`, the argument to the function, or you want to manually, after inserting the HTML do `$(el).on('click', function() { var val = this.dataset.value; /*...*/ });`

Comment: Progress.  Since doing: onclick="reject('${d.user_id}')" I now have the error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" empApproveRej.html:296:31

Comment: that seems like your backend is giving you an error instead of the json you wanted. line 296 is out of sight in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: the computer is telling you that the stuff you got back isnt json. console.log it and see what it is

Comment: Thank you very much for your expertise.  Solved.